# Convert .dwg to .shp via FME

Tags: shapefile, dwg, fme-form

I'm attempting to convert a .dwg to .shp with FME software. So far I have pulled in the .dwg, added the writer to convert to a shapefile with a specified coord system and chose the location of the output dataset, and now my screen looks like this but I do not know how to actually access or move/save these shapefiles so I can open in arcmap.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to join the two sides together by dragging connections from each input to each output (click on the yellow arrow and drag a line from it to the equivalent red one). Then press the green run button on the toolbar and the translation will run.

Quicker way to generate it in the future is to start with the empty canvas and press Ctrl+G. That gives you a dialog to define both reader and writer and will automatically connect the two sides.